# Is there a *very* lightweight IDE for .net?

Tags: .net, ide

Does anyone know of a good lightweight IDE for .net? Often times I open VS and create a new project just to see if a line compiles, to test a quick method, or something trivial like that.

Essentially what I want is an app similar to notepad I can open, have the basic class structure already defined, and be able to compile/run it. It would be fine if it was always a console app.

Comment: Don't forget to vote up the question fellow SOers. Anyone developer working with .Net should have this as a tool in his/her belt. Jeff Key, the developer of Snippet Compiler deserves a giant Kudos.

Answer (score 23):

Check out [Snippet Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/).  I use it often, it's very small and minimizes to the system tray until you need it.

[image: Screenshot of SnippetCompiler in action on i.stack.imgur]

Answer (score 13):

Personally, I've run into a lot of friction using Snippet Compiler.

So, I tend to use [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to test snippets.  It's pretty convenient for testing individual lines of code, or most "full" program snippets, as well as evaluating LINQ statements against a database.

It features a really awesome view of results, so that complex types are displayed in an easy-to-read structure.

[From their site](http://www.linqpad.net/CodeSnippetIDE.aspx):

> - LINQPad reports the execution time in the status bar, so you won't have to manually create a Stopwatch class for performance testing.
> - Want to test a variation of your snippet? Ctrl+Shift+C instantly clones your snippet so you can run another version side-by-side.
> - You can return to saved queries in single click, thanks to the My Queries treeview. Some people are using LINQPad as a scripting tool!

<del>The only real snag that run into with LINQPad is in the "full program" mode (where you're defining methods, instead of just calling individual statements) you can't create extension methods, because everything happens inside of a the context of a hidden type (and extension methods can't be defined in a nested type).</del>This has since been addressed, and LINQPad supports defining extension methods now.

Comment: Nice find. i'm definitely going to try it out. Also seems like a great way to practice LINQ - important for a guy trying to get 3.5 from 2.0!

Comment: Interesting.  +1 for introducing me to a new tool.  Just to ask, what were the issues you had with Snippet Compiler?  I have been using it for several years without any issues.

Comment: I think the problems that I had were around including references/namespaces, and setting up supporting classes/methods outside of the Main method.  However, it's been a while, so I don't remember the exact details.

Comment: I reach for LINQPad, too, since it allows me the ability to accomplish just one expression or one statement worth of work, without the surrounding class definition. This helps me think more functionally. LINQPad also runs F#, so I can try to express myself in that language, too; making it a great learning tool.

Answer (score 9):

By using the **vsvars32.bat** file provided by Microsoft, it only takes a [minimal amount](http://www.zeusedit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1235) of configuration to run the C# *csc.exe* compiler from the command line.

So in general, any editor that can run a third party tool could be configured to run the C# compiler from within the editor.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not stick with C#, I'd recommend you to use F# interactive or IronPython console.

Comment: +1 awesome advice for testing assemblies etc on the fly. IronRUby is cute at that too :)

Answer (score 4):

just create a text file, save it as .cs and call the compiler from the command line, or create a batch file that takes the filename as parameter.

Here's the lowdown on the C# 2.0 compiler command line : [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Find an interpreter:

- [CSI](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csi.aspx)
- [CSharpInterpreter](http://www.devhood.com/tools/tool_details.aspx?tool_id=641)
- [Mono mint](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mint)

Or use notepad++ (or something similar) and make a script that runs the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

[QuickSharp](http://quicksharp.sourceforge.net/) is pretty good.

Here's the description from the home page:

> QuickSharp is a streamlined integrated
>   development environment for
>   Microsoft's .NET platform; it provides
>   a simple, uncluttered development
>   approach that lets you get programming
>   in an instant. QuickSharp doesn't use
>   solutions or projects, programs and
>   libraries are developed as individual
>   files making development a breeze.
>   With QuickSharp you can work closer to
>   the .NET Framework development tools
>   and learn to use the most advanced
>   development platform for Windows from
>   the ground up.

Answer (score 2):

I would check the [C# Express Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vcsharp/) (If you are using C#).  I leave it open with a basic console project already loaded.  I just paste the code I want into that to quickly see if it compiles.

Answer (score 2):

[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) is pretty nice.  I've not used it for C# (I mainly work on the OS stack) but I used it for small console IronPython program a couple of months back and it was a joy to work with.

Answer (score 2):

[LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net) is also very lightweight (and free)

[ideone](http://ideone.com/) is yet another (but online)

Answer (score 1):

I use command line (PowerShell these days) for that sort of thing, with a few .cs files lying around for common starting templates. Editor is whichever one is your favorite - it's Far+Colorer for me (with hand-tweaked syntax highlighting so that it understands all C# 3.0 and 4.0 keywords), but there are plenty other lightweight options.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [CodeRun](http://coderun.com). It is lightweight a browser-based IDE for .NET, JavaScript and PHP!

Update [08/24/2012]:

http://compilr.com/

Comment: URL gone/btoke sadly.