# Adding References without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

I am trying to learn log4Net, however, I do not have Visual Studio installed in my PC (due to lack of Administrative Privileges). And so, I am trying out my code by writing them in good old Notepad of Windows XP. In this, if I want to add a reference to log4net.dll, how do I do it?

Sorry for being .NET naive. I am just learning!

For instance, this is the sample code that I am trying to execute. Tutorial is available [here](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-1-Getting-Started.aspx).

```
using System;   
namespace Tutorial1_GettingStarted   
{   
 class Program   
 {   
     static void Main( string[] args )   
     {   
      log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure();   
      log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger( typeof( Program ) );              

        log.Debug( "Hello World!" );   
        log.Info( "I'm a simple log4net tutorial." );   
        log.Warn( "... better be careful ..." );   
        log.Error( "ruh-roh: an error occurred" );   
        log.Fatal( "OMG we're dooooooomed!" );   

        Console.ReadLine();  // so you can read the output   
    }   
  }   
}
```

Comment: I would suggest asking a person that does have admin rights [IT?] to install it for you, because .NET coding is going to pretty painful without it.

Comment: @Nathan, there are a lot of other .NET IDEs.  See [
Is there a *very* lightweight IDE for .net?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638972/is-there-a-very-lightweight-ide-for-net) and [
What is the best alternative IDE to Visual Studio 2008
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310735/what-is-the-best-alternative-ide-to-visual-studio-2008) for a start.

Comment: Agreed, the first link is very good. I was mainly getting to the lack of admin rights, it's hard to do things when yo can't install a IDE.

Comment: Nathan: Thanks for the suggestions. But, when you work for a Service Company, there is only so much that can be done at office. :-) However, at home, I have a VMWare setup of Windows 2003/SQLServer 2005, Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition. So, the weekend and evenings are pretty. It is just the minutes that I sneak in between office hours where it becomes painful. I will have to, unfortunately, live with it.

Comment: Mathew: +1 for the lightweight IDE questions on SO.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you compile, use the [`/r` switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yabyz3h4.aspx):

```
csc Program.cs /r:Log4Net.dll
```