# What are some lightweight editors for C#?

Tags: c#, ide

Are there any lightweight C# IDEs/compilers?
Visual Studio is great but I find it annoying to create an extra project for every single file. Isn't there something like SciTE where you can simply type in the code, compile and run it in the console?

Comment: Why do you create an extra project for every single file??

Comment: ***Visual Studio is great but I find it annoying to create an extra project for every single file*** ??? ehhh??

Comment: Sorry, I think I expressed myself in a wrong way. Actually I just started learning C# by watching Video-Tutorials.

Comment: * And for every topic from the Video-Tutorial I have to make an extra project.

Comment: Try to learn C# without ditching and avoid learning how to use the premier tool used to develop C#.  Leverage temporary projects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a *very* lightweight IDE for .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638972/is-there-a-very-lightweight-ide-for-net)

Comment: @abatishchev He meant he has to create a new project every time he wants to experiment with some new code. You've been there I'm sure... testing different DB methods... algorithms, whatever.

Answer (score 16):

Hands down (for me) is LINQPad - it does so much more than LINQ.

http://linqpad.net/

Answer (score 12):

Personally I just use a lightweight text editor ([jed](http://www.jedsoft.org/jed/), or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) and a separate console. I typically make the console open in `c:\users\jon\Test` where there's a `Test.cs` file with whatever I've done last - typically including:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
// etc

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
    }
}
```

I normally just get rid of whatever was in `Main` before and put in whatever I want.

While compiling from the editor would potentially be handy, I often want to use ILDasm or Reflector, so it's handy having the console open.

You might also want to look at [LINQPad](http://linqpad.com) which would help you: it has Intellisense, and can build and run code directly. It's particularly aimed at helping with LINQ queries (hence the name) but you can use it in a more general-purpose way too.

Answer (score 3):

[CS-Script Plugin (CSScript.Npp)](https://csscriptnpp.codeplex.com/) is exactly what are you looking for.

Comment: I was going to flag this as VLQ, but it's the Question that must be closed as Asking for Recommendation.

Comment: @brasofilo : what is VLQ?

Comment: @Luke, Very Low Quality... answers with just a link are put on the VLQ review where users can vote to delete it

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)

Answer (score 1):

#develop is a free Integrated Development Environment (IDE) for C#, VB.NET, Boo, IronPython, IronRuby and F# projects on Microsoft's .NET platform. It is written (almost) entirely in C#, and comes with features you would expect in an IDE plus a few more.

The #develop project started on September 11th, 2000.

http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Absolutely true. Corrected.

Comment: This project is now more or less dead. It only supports up to c# 5, which is now 5 years old.

Answer (score 1):

I used to swear by SnippetCompiler, but [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is awesome for running snippets as well as great LINQ running capabilities. If you use AutoCompletion (license), it's even better.

[Full Disclosure: I know the author of LINQPad, Joe Albahari, but I wouldn't endorse anything that didn't stand on its own merit.]

Answer (score 1):

You can also configure Visual Studio to not save the project file when you create one.  I do this all the time to explore namespaces.  I love Snippet Compiler, but the autocomplete options are not nearly as good.

The option is under Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > "Save new projects when created"  When you uncheck this, it will create a project in a temp directory that will get cleaned up when you close that instance of Visual Studio.  Should you choose to save your work, you can use "Save All" to get a dialog that will allow you to specify a save location for the project.

I also took the default text of a Snippet Compiler file and have that as a snippet in Visual Studio.  SC's default file wraps your code in a try/catch block and provides shortcut functions for Console.WriteLine().

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyClass
{
    public static void RunSnippet()
    {

    }

    #region Helper methods

    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            RunSnippet();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string error = string.Format("---\nThe following error occurred while executing the snippet:\n{0}\n---", e.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(error);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    private static void WL(object text, params object[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text.ToString(), args);
    }

    private static void RL()
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Break()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will surely like [Snippet Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/).

You might as well like [SharDevelop](http://download.cnet.com/SharpDevelop/3000-2212_4-10517125.html).